# redshift leader node using up 100% of disk

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, pipeline, leader

[image]we have a 50 node redshift cluster, and we run vacuum periodically. and currently we are running a pipeline where we are moving some data onto S3 and deleting it from redshift.

after about 2 weeks of processing. our disk usage on 49 nodes ( except leader ) came down from 95% to 80%. but the disk usage on leader went up and its now at 100%.

I tried rebooting the cluster to see if there were transient files that were holding the space. but that didnt help.

any suggestion would be a great help at this point.

thanks!

Comment: This looks like an excellent question to ask [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/). You can ask for advice, raise issues and seek expert advice. The cost is probably less than the time you've spent so far on this issue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I agree with you. but how shall I put it... , thats not an option for me.

Comment: is anything running?

Comment: Hi @bhavin, Did you find the root cause of this? I too face the same problem but don't have any clue.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some "skewed" tables, which means tables are not distributed on the nodes evenly, the following SQL will give you list of tables and based on `skew` column, you might need to redistribute your tables.

```
select trim(pgn.nspname) as schema, 
trim(a.name) as table, id as tableid, 
decode(pgc.reldiststyle,0, 'even',1,det.distkey ,8,'all') as distkey, dist_ratio.ratio::decimal(10,4) as skew, 
det.head_sort as "sortkey", 
det.n_sortkeys as "#sks", b.mbytes,  
decode(b.mbytes,0,0,((b.mbytes/part.total::decimal)*100)::decimal(5,2)) as pct_of_total, 
decode(det.max_enc,0,'n','y') as enc, a.rows, 
decode( det.n_sortkeys, 0, null, a.unsorted_rows ) as unsorted_rows , 
decode( det.n_sortkeys, 0, null, decode( a.rows,0,0, (a.unsorted_rows::decimal(32)/a.rows)*100) )::decimal(5,2) as pct_unsorted 
from (select db_id, id, name, sum(rows) as rows, 
sum(rows)-sum(sorted_rows) as unsorted_rows 
from stv_tbl_perm a 
group by db_id, id, name) as a 
join pg_class as pgc on pgc.oid = a.id
join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace
left outer join (select tbl, count(*) as mbytes 
from stv_blocklist group by tbl) b on a.id=b.tbl
inner join (select attrelid, 
min(case attisdistkey when 't' then attname else null end) as "distkey",
min(case attsortkeyord when 1 then attname  else null end ) as head_sort , 
max(attsortkeyord) as n_sortkeys, 
max(attencodingtype) as max_enc 
from pg_attribute group by 1) as det 
on det.attrelid = a.id
inner join ( select tbl, max(mbytes)::decimal(32)/min(mbytes) as ratio 
from (select tbl, trim(name) as name, slice, count(*) as mbytes
from svv_diskusage group by tbl, name, slice ) 
group by tbl, name ) as dist_ratio on a.id = dist_ratio.tbl
join ( select sum(capacity) as  total
from stv_partitions where part_begin=0 ) as part on 1=1
where mbytes is not null 
order by  mbytes desc
```

Comment: @mdemy thanks for your suggestion , but I believe skewed rows would occure on the compute nodes and not leader.

Comment: there are no skewed rows but there are skewed tables. your comment above suggest you need more reading to do to understand how redshift works. good luck

Comment: not sure I follow @mdemy. how can you have skewed table without skewed row(s). can you point me to the doc you might be referring to..  please dont get me wrong , just trying to find pointers.